# will mysqldump lockout select or read only based queries

Tags: backup, mysql-replication, mysql, database-backup

i have a large database to backup nightly and we currently do mysqldump on the master server which locks all inserts when dumping

we use a master slave mysql setup with magento configured to send all writes to the master and all reads to the slave. if we move the backup to the slave server will the mysqldump process lock out select queries or any other queries that would be reading data only and not inserting data to the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqldump uses a read local lock, so selects will still work

sources:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html (see sections on READ and LOCAL keywords)

Comment: can confirm testing this worked perfectly :)